# A weird “such” inversion

Tags: inversion

Is “So beautiful a day was it that...” grammatically correct? Does such a weird case of inversion even exist?

I know that this question doesn’t hold up in terms of pertinence or practicality but the Vietnamese’s EngLish curriculum sometimes forces you to resort to such ridiculous outlandish grammar. I tried looking many ways on the net yet no blogs or articles showed up.

I am aware of the other types of inversion that can resolve this problem with ease, such as “Such a beautiful day was it that...” but like I said, Vietnamese curriculum, if you know you know.

Comment: Yes, it is grammatically correct. However, it is not used often nowadays. Such a style was more common before 1940 or so.

Comment: Thank you very much, I never thought I’d get an answer for at least days. Have a good one.